# Why doesnt the OR logical operator( || ) work?

Tags: c, logical-operators

I tried to use the OR logical operator in a do-while statement but for some reason it wouldn't work.

It would work with no OR logical operators(only with one statement) but otherwise no.

```
int main()
{
    char ansr;

    do
    {
        printf("What do you want to do?\n");
        printf("A = Add Employee\nR = Remove Employee\nE = Exit\n");
        scanf(" %c", &ansr);
    }while(ansr != 'E'||ansr != 'e');

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever i would write 'E' or 'e' I would expect the program to get out of the while loop but for some reason it would keep going through the do-while statement.

Comment: The condition `x != A || x != B` is true for every unequal `A` and `B`. You want `&&` and not `||`.

Comment: Alternatively (and equivalently), modify the scope of the logical negations: `!(ansr == 'E' || ansr == 'e')`.

Comment: If `ansr` is equal to `E`, it must be not equal to `e`.  The simplest way to address this is with `toupper()` or `tolower()`  with somthing like  `while ( toupper( ansr ) != 'E' )`.

Comment: A tip is to make a habit of reading the expression loud (or at least in your head): "while answer is not 'E' or answer is not 'e', loop". Wait, that doesn't sound right, surely it should say "answer is not 'E'  _and_ answer is not 'e'".

Comment: (Also, studying some basic boolean algebra and De Morgan's laws is good stuff for programmers.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logical OR (||) means "if either of these is true."  In your case, if the input is not 'E' or it's not 'e' then it will perform another iteration.  This is always true since even if it's one of them it's not going to be the other.

You're probably thinking of logical AND (&&):

```
while (ansr != 'E' && ansr != 'e');
```

This means "if both of these are true."  If ansr is either 'E' or 'e', one of the clauses will be false, and the whole expression will then become false.